# to recognize name of person with prebuilt entities in luis

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created a new Intent in luis App And i gave a sample example as I am john smith how can we get or recognize name of any person(john smith) in luis

Answer (score 1):

The only prebuilt entity for person names is in entertainment. Hence, you can learn your app by this entity. See more details about this entity [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-domains#entertainment).

Answer (score 0):

> how can we get or recognize name of any person(john smith) in luis

As we know, person’s name could be anything. It could not be 100% intelligent to identify something as a name. If your LUIS app do not recognize some names, you can try to use [phrase list features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature), which can help LUIS recognize intents and entities.

Besides, this SO thread:[LUIS - understand any person name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182873/luis-understand-any-person-name) discussed about person name recognition, you can refer to it.